# Running fig = plt.figure() in pandas opens two figures

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Pretty much what it says in the title.. most pandas examples suggest doing `fig = plt.figure()` before `df.plot(..)`. But if I do that, two figures pop up after `plt.show()` - the first completely empty and the second with the actual pandas figure.. Any ideas why?

Comment: Are you running this in ipython? If so you don't need the `plt.show()` call as matplotlib will be configured to be inline

Comment: nop, just a usual python script

Comment: @EdChum this is not by default like that. For inline figures, you have to specifically activate it with eg `%matplotlib inline`

Comment: @Martin you are correct. The `plt.figure` is not needed, as `df.plot()` will by default create a new figure (unless you specify an Axes object to plot it on with the `ax` keyword)

Comment: thanks, that actually helped me get a bit closer to a solution in creating two plots inside one in pandas too, https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/9779

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a DataFrame, `df.plot(..)` will create a new figure, unless you provide an Axes object to the `ax` keyword argument.
So you are correct that the `plt.figure()` is not needed in this case. The `plt.figure()` calls in the pandas documentation should be removed, as they indeed are not needed. There is an issue about this: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/8776

What you can do with the `ax` keyword is eg:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df.plot(..., ax=ax)
```

Note that when plotting a series, this will by default plot on the 'current' axis (`plt.gca()`) if you don't provide `ax`.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer, was indeed kind of obvious, but so confusing due to the call's persistence in the documentation